# JSP - Using <c:set> with target, target being a variable

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am new to JSP, so maybe this is a stupid question. I know that is possible to use `<c:set>` like this in JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
<c:set target="${myBean}" property="x" value="y"/>
```

But this restricts the id of the bean to being a literal. Is there any way to use a variable instead? Something like this:

```
<c:set var="myBeanName" value="myBean" />
<jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
<c:set target="${${myBeanName}}" property="x" value="y"/>
```

I know that probably the `${${}}` syntax is wrong, is just to give the idea of what I want to do. Is it possible? If so, how?

EDIT: In this case I want to allocate maps with different names and be able to access them later programmatically, without actually knowing their names. For example let's say I want to allocate two maps and map1name, map2name are defined somewhere in the code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="${map1name}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="${map2name}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
// What now? How do I access the map whose id is map1name?
```

I hope it is clearer now. :)

EDIT2: Tried Bashir@ solution, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token "$", = expected after this token
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token ";", enum expected after this token
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token "}", Expression expected after this token
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on tokens, EnumHeader expected instead
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token "}", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete MethodDeclaration
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete EnumBody
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on tokens, EnumHeader expected instead
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error on token ",", invalid (
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file:
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
4: <c:set var="myBeanName" value="${param.name}" />
5: <jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do? with given example

Comment: Example provided @Bashir, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: thanks, I hope my answer bellow helps you

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry I have not tried it yet. I am writing the code now and then deploy it to my server :)

Comment: please provide more details about this bean and param, how are they imported?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<c:set var="myBeanName" value="myBean" />
<jsp:useBean id="${myBeanName}" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
<c:set target="${pageScope[myBeanName]}" property="x" value="y"/>
```

and if the JSTL variable is coming from request, use:

```
<c:set target="${requestScope[myBeanName]}" property="x" value="y"/>
```

EDIT:

After your edit (Which is different from the initial statement), I suggest to use:

```
<jsp:useBean id="<%=param.name%>" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
```